# tinymce custom font size entered into font size list

Tags: jquery, tinymce, font-size

I know how to increase the font-size options in TinyMCE, but what I'd like to add the option where the user can enter their own font-size values.

I'm currently using this option in the tinyMCE init function:

```
theme_advanced_font_sizes : 
"8=8px,10=10px,12=12px,14=14px,16=16px,18=18px,20=20px,22=22px,24=24px,26=26px,28=28px,30=30px,32=32px,34=34px,36=36px,38=38px,40=40px,42=42px,44=44px,46=46px,48=48px,50=50px,52=52px,54=54px,56=56px,58=58px,60=60px,62=62px,64=64px,66=66px,68=68px,70=70px,72=72px,74=74px,76=76px,78=78px,80=80px",
```

But what if the user wants to use 12.5? So I want for this to be something like an input-selection box, not just a selection box.

I mean, like the way it is in MS Word, sort of like an input-select control:

[image]

How can we add this control or edit the existing one to turn it into this?

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that this setting gets read on editor initialization you will have to create the string for `theme_advanced_font_sizes` before you init the editor.
The other way is to reinit the edit with this setting. After the user chooses however the desired option you shutdown tinymce and reinit it. For the configuration this will do:

```
theme_advanced_font_sizes : "8=8px,10=10px,12=12.5px ..."
```

Comment: Thanks, but actually my question is slightly different. In the current instance of TinyMCE, it is not possible for the user to choose 12.5px because "12.5px" is not one of the options available. So how can we turn this into more than a selection, a selection list that allows user to type in a desired font size as well.

Comment: you will have to define a mean for the user to insert such a setting and then reinit the tinymce in order to show this

Comment: that's what my question is - how can we make such a control? I've edited my question to clarify it with an image. I checked the TinyMCE documentation - they have a SplitButton control but I couldn't find a control like this one.

Comment: you want that control inside the tinymce toolbar?

Comment: yes, basically an enhancement of the existing font-size control - but if that's not possible then a separate control in the toolbar.

Comment: a control that functions like what? i think it should be something like an inputfield to let the user enter a label and the desired size, both should get added to the theme_advanced_font_sizes string and the editor reinitialized

Comment: it would take me some time to develope that

Comment: okay..thanks! i thought so too. i'll just tell my boss told hold his horses. do you mind if i ask you how long it would take you if you did it? just to get an idea for myself...

Comment: to create non-standard tinymce controls or tweak them is a bit a opain in the ass - i guess it would take about 3-5 hours

Comment: Were you able to create a combobox for font size within TinyMCE?  I'm looking for the same thing. Thanks